# Could hacker change data in one smart contract with out call contract function?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

Consider a Contract:

```
Contract Example{
    uint array[];
    address owner;
    function Example(){
        owner = msg.sender
    }
    function setArray(uint index, uint value) public {
        if (msg.sender == owner){
            array[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any possible that hacker update array[] directly by generate a specific block. (steer clear of the condition that "only owner can update array")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything's possible.

But assuming the basic security of the blockchain is intact, no, nothing but the smart contract itself is allowed to modify its storage.

Comment: Hi @smarx My question basically is: Is there any mechanism to let miner realize that contract content been changed illegally?

Comment: Contract storage can only be changed via a transaction. All transactions are checked for validity by all nodes in the network. (They all check the signature on each transaction and rerun all the transactions in every block.)